# Windows 10 - Get name of all apps which prevent windows from shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

There is one app without name which always prevents windows from shutting down.

Is there a way to figure this out without having to uninstall all apps one after another and test again and again?

[image]

Someone asked the question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power-winpc/app-with-no-name-preventing-shutdown/7f286f3b-1d1a-4575-b389-f49a871df264?page=1), but the microsoft staff was unable to even understand the problem.

Comment: Juts press Cancel and check the taskmanager afterwards which (user) processes are still running.

Comment: If you were a programmer, this would be an easy program to write.  You would send the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message to all top level windows and record which ones return FALSE.  You never know if people know how to code or not.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, can you write it?

Comment: Yes, I *could* write it.. but I am not going to.  Sorry.

Comment: Why are you even commenting then, if you don't try to be useful at all? Reported for trolling.